# copying a file to a hard link

Tags: linux, cp, hardlink

I recently got bit by a misbehaving in a bash script of mine and was wondering:

1. is this the expected system behavior, or is it a bug
2. what are the ideal workarounds

Essentially, the problem boiled down to this. First I had an existing directory structure with  the following layout.

- `/opt/dir/file.a`
- `/opt/dir/file.b`
- `/opt/dir/file`

where `file` is a **hard link** to `file.a`. I wanted to replace `file` with a shell script which selected `file.a` or `file.b` depending on parameters, so I ran something like this:

```
cp my_file /opt/dir/file
```

The problem is that since `file` is a hard link to `file.a`, (meaning that the two files are really just two names for the same inode), the change was reflected under both `file` and `file.a`. This was **obviously** not what what I wanted.

It seems that the `cp` command effectively opened `/opt/dir/file` with the truncate file flag something like: `fopen("file", "w+")`. and wrote to it. I was expecting it to break the hard link since I was copying a **new** file to that name.

Is this the correct and expected behavior of `cp`? It seems unintuitive to me. When I copy a file from one location to another, in my mind I am replacing it, not rewriting it. Is there a flag for `cp` to avoid this? My current work-around is that I `rm /opt/dir/file && cp my_file /opt/dir/file`.

Looking at the man page it **appears** that `cp --remove-destination my_file /opt/dir/file` may be the correct solution, but I am still interested in what everyone has to say on the subject.

Comment: Actually it is very intuitively for me. It is the same file. You write to the same file. Both places get the updated content. But what is intuitive will vary per person and it is hard to give one clear, perfect answer. Just opinions. IMHO that makes it off-topic.

Comment: @Hennes, thanks for your response. I would say that there is a difference between "hard to answer" and "off topic". Certainly the answer may be "primarily opinion based" but that's a different story. I would like to clarify the reason I found it unintuitive. I know that writing to one updates both, **but**, my mental image of a copy is to "replace" the destination, not "update" it. However, I do understand your point/

Comment: I think the question is both hard to answer, will have opinions, is interesting and is well written. For me three of those make it a good question on [Su]. `Is there a flag for cp to avoid this?` makes it an actual answerable question. (which you self answered).

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is the correct behavior for `cp`, not a bug.  Given the outcome you are looking for, the modification you made to your script (`rm` followed by `cp`) sounds like the right approach.